# Process Scheduling mechanism in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement a new scheduling mechanism for Linux 2.4.18 as part of a HW assignment.
I have the following problem:
In the new mechanism I need to change the epoch when the active queue is not empty, to do that I need to transfer all the process from the active queue to the expired and then switch between the expired and the active.
How can I go over all the process in the active queue in order to transfer them to the expired?

I tried going over all the 140 bitmaps that have the value 1 and in each one I user for_each_task and removed from the active and inserted to the expired.

But for some reason when I change to the new mechanism (using a system call) the system resets itself.

My thought it that maybe it's too hard for the system to go over so many processes during the schedule function?

Any ideas?

This is the code I wrote in the schedule function

```c
for(int i=0;i<140;i++)
{

    if(this_rq()->active->bitmap[i])
    {
        list_t* iterator;
        list_t* queue=this_rq()->active->queue;
        list_for_each(iterator, queue + i)
        {
            task_t* p = list_entry(iterator,task_t,run_list);
            dequeue_task(p,this_rq()->active);
            enqueue_task(p,this_rq()->expired);
        }   

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do this in a Virtual Machine, and remote-debug with gdb over serial. It will help you work through subsequent bugs in your hw much faster -- you'll be able to set a breakpoint where your code is, and step through to see exactly why the kernel dies.

For example, if you are using VirtualBox, you can follow the instructions [here](http://fotis.loukos.me/blog/?p=25)

You also need to [enable kgdb](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/KGDB) in your kernel.